# location.getSpeed() works on Samsung Galaxy Nexus but not on Galaxy S

Tags: android, performance, navigation, gps, location

i want to display the current speed in my app. on the Galaxy Nexus it works fine but the Galaxy S only displays 0.0 i use the following code to get the speed.

```
location.getSpeed()
```

From the documentation i know:

> **public float getSpeed ()** 
>   Since: API Level 1
>   Returns the speed of the device over ground in meters/second. If hasSpeed() is false, 0.0f is >returned.

can it be that hasSpeed is false on Galaxy S? BUt the function should work since API level 1 so i don't understand where the problem could be.

can anyone help?

thx

Edit:

```
if(location.hasSpeed())
{
    speed = (location.getSpeed()*3.6);
}
else
{
    if(lastLoc!=null)
        {
            double time=(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastUpdate)*1000;
            speed=(location.distanceTo(lastLoc)/time)*3.6;
        }
}
```

Comment: why don't you log `hasSpeed()` and see if it's true or false on your Galaxy S ?

Comment: because i have a custome ROM on the galaxy S where logging is disabled and not possible to enable =(

Comment: you may put a text on the screen which says if `hasSpeed()` is true or false

Comment: ok it is false everytime. even when the location has changed. do you know how to change this?

Comment: and on the Nexus it is true every time. wtf?

Comment: this might have something to do with your custom ROM, can you try another phone or reflash factory image?

Comment: i only have this 2 phones. but perhaps i ca try on a friends phone

Comment: also added some lines of code perhaps they will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok looks like gps is buggy on my galaxy s. tried an other gps speedometer of the market and it also couldn't disply any speed.

i also found out that GPS on the Samsung Galaxy S is realy crap. so well i will have to live with it =)